# get content from variable whose name is taken from another variable

Tags: bash, variables, eval, fastq

I am doing some shell scripting.

I use this construction for creating new variables:

```
eval ${ARG}_ext=fastq
```

which works pretty nice because then I can use those newly created variable directly like this:

```
$file_ext
```

Now I want to assign value to the variable called extension:

```
extension=
```

The assigned value should be one found in variable ${ARG}_ext. Please, how can i do that?

I have tried

```
extension=eval ${ARG}_ext;
```

but this gives me name of the variable and I want its value. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$ extension=$(eval "echo \$${ARG}_ext")
```

Comment: This is working, thank you :-)) (and I also understand your code, nice little trick)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but have you considered using associative arrays instead:

```
declare -A myhash
ARG=file
myhash[${ARG}_ext]='fastq'
extension="${myhash[${ARG}_ext]}"
echo "$extension"
```

Note that declare creates a local variable if used inside a function, so declare the associated array in global scope if you need it globally. (The newest versions of bash add a -g (global) option to declare that solves this issue.)